# Convert list of dictionaries to dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch

I want to convert the list of dictionary to a dictionary 
and the dictionary should be as it is exact copy of the list of dictionary.

I currently have this output stored in one variable which is a list of dictionaries-

```
[{'title': 'some dta', 'author': 'soem dta ', 'responses': 'some data', 'views': 'some dta ', 'lastte': "sommedta", 'last_post_by': 'by In Omnibus'}, {'title':,'Voting',' etc. etc. etc. }]
```

and I want this stored into another variable which can be called from anywhere in the program

```
{'title': 'some data ', 'author': 'some data ', 'responses': 'some data ', 'views': '897 views', 'last_post_date': "Sun 28th Aug '16, 7:05am", 'last_post_by': 'by somedata'}, {'key','value','key',value' }, 
{ etc. etc. etc. }
```

I tried this-

```py
dct = {}
for sub_dict in dictionary:
    dct.update(sub_dict)

print(dct) #here the last element of list is printed as dictionary but, I want to store all the data of dictionary in one variable and use it later in the elasticsearch body
```

That data is going inside elasticsearch index

Comment: The list allows different entries to have different titles. If you merge them all, that doesn't seem any different that taking one item out of the list and just using it.

Comment: So what should I do to convert it into a single dictionary

Comment: I earlier had to convert into list because, the dictionary was over writing

Comment: It's overwriting because dictionary has unique keys. There are few ways to make it into single dictionary (e.g. have values as lists - title:['title1','title2']). What is your expected output of a single dictionary for these dictionaries? And is elasticsearch able to take this kind of single dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this:

```
list_of_articles = [article0, article1, ... article99]
```

If you want to do something with an article, it is as simple as this

```
article = list_of_articles[22]
dostuff(article)
```

But what you're talking about is take ALL the articles (which are distinct for a reason) and mashing them together. If they all have the same keys, you will just end up with the last article, but if some of them have different keys, you'll get those mixed in with the last article.

Of course, article could be a class, but more likely it's a simple dict which exactly matches the code you have posted in the original question. I've just tried to conceal that until now.

Addendum from comments: to change from "list of dict" to "dict of dict" is really easy IF it makes sense for the data.

```
dict_of_dict = {article['title']: article for article in list_of_articles}
```

Of course this will fail unless every article has a distinct title. And it will be inferior to list_of_articles if you aren't actually using the title for lookup (my opinion at least).

Comment: See, basically I stored the data inside the list of dictionaries first and when, I tried to covert it into the dictionary I had major problems. 
total 6 keys are there and there are multiple dictionaries stored in a single list 
I have values in list as [{'key':'val','key':val' total 6 times}, {'key':'val','key':val' total 6 times} {'key':'val','key':val', 'key':'val', 'key':val'}, etc ]   
and yes 
you mentioned about mashing it up I want to mash things up at one place

I don't want to do anything with that list 
Just convert it into dictionary and store all data in one variable

Comment: All the data is already in one variable, which is a list of dict.

Comment: so how can we convert it to dictionary containing multiple dictionaries

Comment: Oh that's easy, if each dictionary has a UNIQUE value. Want to edit your question?

Comment: I have added that to my answer, with some assumptions about what you meant.